# Is pressure the dot product between Force and the of normal vector time area?

Tags: pressure, vectors

Don't know if an inverse vector is defined for normal vector, or if I should use the area vector itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d\vec F = (-) P \;d\vec A$ is the vector equation.

$\vec F$ is the force normal to the surface, with $P$ the pressure and area $dA$ consider a vector in a direction normal to the surface $\hat n$, so $d \vec A = dA \; \hat n $.

Some people put the minus sign in to signify that the force is acting towards the area and by convention the normal vector points away from an area.

In terms of magnitude the equation is written as $dF = P \; dA$.